# How to run GridSearchCV without cross-validation?

Tags: scikit-learn

I would like to run a regular 'gridsearch without the CV', i.e. I don't want to cross-validate, but setting `cv=1` is not allowed.

I am doing this because I am using a classifier to draw decision boundaries and visualize/understand my data instead of predicting labels, and do not care about the generalization error. I would like to minimize the training error instead.

EDIT: I guess I'm really asking two questions

1. How to hack `cv=1` in `GridSearchCV`? Answered by ogrisel below
2. Does it make sense to do a gridsearch to minimize training error instead of generalization error, and if so, how would I do that? I suspect it involves inserting my own scoring function for the `scoring` parameter in `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: What do you then need `GridSearchCV` for? If you don't need bootstrapped samples, you can just do something like `[score(y_test, Classifier(**args).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)) for args in parameters]`

Comment: Well, okay, you would need to "unroll" your `parameters` list from the scikit-learn's `GridSearchCV` format to a list of all possible combinations (like cartesian product of all lists).

Comment: ParameterGrid is public: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid.html#sklearn.grid_search.ParameterGrid not that it does any magic..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there easy way to grid search without cross validation in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624978/is-there-easy-way-to-grid-search-without-cross-validation-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass an instance of `ShuffleSplit(test_size=0.20, n_splits=1, random_state=0)` as the `cv` parameter.

That will do a single CV split per parameter combination ([sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html)).

Comment: This worked (after remembering to add `n=len(X)`). Is this '1-fold CV', where we 2-fold, but strictly train on the 0.8 split and test on the 0.2 split only, instead of traditional 2-fold where both folds play the role of train and test? This appears to solve my application question of how to set `cv=1` and not the theoretical question of minimizing training error instead of generalization error. However I'm starting to find the latter not worthwhile.

Comment: There is no way to use `GridSearchCV` to minimize the training error. You will have to write your own class to do so.

Comment: Where should one add the `n` ?