# Random search without cross validation in python/sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

If you want to do grid search in sklearn *without* cross validation (what `GridSearchCV` does), you can apparently use the `ParameterGrid` class (see here: [Is there easy way to grid search without cross validation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624978/is-there-easy-way-to-grid-search-without-cross-validation-in-python)). Does anyone know of a similar method to do random search without CV (i.e. the equivalent of `RandomizedSearchCV`)?

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer myself, you can use the `ParameterSampler` class from sklearn (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html#sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler)), it behaves similar to `ParameterGrid`.